# Hashing Sequences of Integers

Tags: c, hash

I have to deal with sequences of numbers, where a sequence has the following properties:

- The elements are integers,
- the lengths of the sequences vary and is not fixed,
- the integers have an upper bound,
- multiple occurrences of elements is allowed,
- the order of elements does not matter.

Given a sequence, I'd like to know if this sequence has already occurred, that is I want to hash sequences. For example,

```
[2, 3, 6, 2, 13]
```

and

```
[6, 3, 2, 13, 2]
```

should have the same hash values.

The programming language being used is C.

I know that I could first sort the sequences and then store them in a trie, which is definitely an option. Nevertheless, what would be an appropriate hash function for this purpose?

Comment: So they're really more sets than sequences, right? Since the order doesn't matter?

Comment: A plain old XOR would be a reasonable place to start.

Comment: @harold Yes, you are right. In fact, these are multisets.

Comment: @Hot Licks I'm sorry, how should the XOR be done exactly?

Comment: "the integers may have an upper bound which is not known beforehand"... If there are finitely many sets, and each set has finite size, then you can be more specific and state that "the integers definitely have an upper bound...". Although I'm not entirely sure that fact is really pertinent to this question. One idea would be to put each set into some canonical form (e.g. sort it), and generate a good hash (MD5, SHA-*, depending on how many you expect to have) that is resistant to collisions, and store that.

Comment: `hash = a[0] xor a[1] xor a[2] xor a[3] xor ...`

Comment: @twalberg You're right, we can say that the integers do have an upper bound. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll think about it certainly.

Comment: One can at a minimum assume (or hope) that the integers have a upper bound based on the size of the field representing them.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, after I'd read Ilmari Karonen's answer I guessed it could look like this. Thanks!

Comment: The important thing to note is that you want the same hash irrespective of order.  This means you either need an order-insensitive hash, or you need to place the elements in a canonical order (ie, sort them) before you hash.  Order-insensitive hashes would be addition (with overflow), XOR, and a few assorted bit-bashing techniques.  "Canned" hash algorithms are generally (by design) *not* order-insensitive, meaning you must sort before applying them.

Answer (score 4):

The requirement that

> - the order of elements does not matter

makes me immediately think of something like [Zobrist hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing).  That is, you'd have a function `f` mapping integers to random bitstrings, and your hash would be simply the XOR of the bitstrings corresponding to the numbers in your sequence.

Of course, the basic Zobrist hashing described above doesn't satisfy your other requirement that

> - multiple occurrences of elements is allowed

since the XOR operation is its own inverse (i.e. `a XOR a = 0` for any `a`).  However, simply replacing XOR with some other [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29) operation without this property (which, in normal Zobrist hashing, is actually considered desirable), such as *n*-bit addition, should produce a hash like you want:

```c
unsigned int hash_multiset (int *seq, int n) {
    unsigned int h = 0;
    while (n--) h += f( *seq++ );
    return h;
}
```

(A minor detail to note about this function is that, if you want to truncate its output, it's slightly better to use the upper than the lower bits.  This is because, if the *k* lowest bits of the hashes of the sequences `[a]` and `[b]` collide, then so will the *k* lowest bits of `[a, a]`, `[b, b]`, `[a, b]` and so on.  For the *k* highest bits, this is not true, since the lower bits can carry over into the higher ones, producing more "random-looking" output.)

There are various ways to implement the function `f`.  For a limited range of input integers, you could simply use a fixed lookup table of random bitstrings.  Alternatively, if you don't know the range of your inputs in advance, you could use another (ordinary) hash table mapping integers to random bitstrings and just build it up "on the fly".

Finally, it's also possibly to implement `f` *without* a lookup table, simply by using a fixed function that "looks random enough".  One good choice for such a function would be to use a simple and fast [block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher), such as [TEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) or (on systems with hardware support for it) [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), with the output truncated to your preferred hash length.

Comment: This looks really interesting, thank you. Is n = length of sequence?

Comment: Yes. C arrays don't store their own length, so you need to pass it to the function somehow.

Answer (score 1):

How about multiplying all the numbers and the length of the sequence, modulo some reasonably big number? Here's some Scala code that shows the calculation:

```
val l = List(6, 3, 2, 13, 2)
(l.reduce(_ * _) * l.length) % 10000
```

This results in: 4680.

Obviously this does not guarantee that if the hashes match, the sequences are unique. (It might not even be a very good approximation!) However, if the hashes do *not* match, it's guaranteed that the sequences are not the same.

Comment: The integer mod component of this idea pretty much guarantees that if I have 10000 or more sequences, I will have false collisions.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be one option.

Answer (score 0):

Putting perf aside, if you want something easy to review and reliable, I'd go with:

```
var sample = new [] { 11, 55, 12, 3 };
String.Join(" ", sample.OrderBy(i => i)).GetHashCode()
```

You may want to add a call to .Distinct() depending on if you're considering a set instead of a sequence.